# Why does the button get unhighlighted after repuasing?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm facing a really weird issue with the pause menu.
Whenever I pause and then unpause and pause again, the buttons lose their focus.
The first time I pause:

[image]

Second time I pause:

[image]

Only the first time is working as expected, all pauses after that are like the second image(no button highlighted). I couldn't figure out the reason.

[image]

Here is my code:

```
 void Update()
    {
        var gamepad = Gamepad.current;
        var keyboard = Keyboard.current;
        if (gamepad == null && keyboard == null)
            return; // No gamepad connected.
        if ((gamepad != null && gamepad.startButton.wasPressedThisFrame) || (keyboard !=null && keyboard.pKey.wasPressedThisFrame))
        {
            if (GameIsPaused)
            {
                Resume();

            }
            else
            {
                Pause();
            }
        }
    }
    public void Resume()
    {
        player.gameObject.GetComponent<MyPlayerMovement>().enabled = true;
        pauseMenuUI.SetActive(false);
        Time.timeScale = 1f;
        GameIsPaused = false;
      //  GameObject.Find("ThePlayer").GetComponent<MyPlayerMovement>().enabled = false;
      //  GameObject.Find("ThePlayer").GetComponent<InteractIcons>().enabled = false;
    }

    private void Pause()
    {
        player.gameObject.GetComponent<MyPlayerMovement>().enabled = false;
        pauseMenuUI.SetActive(true);
        resumeBtn.Select();
        Time.timeScale = 0f;
        GameIsPaused = true;
     //   GameObject.Find("ThePlayer").GetComponent<MyPlayerMovement>().enabled = true;
      //  GameObject.Find("ThePlayer").GetComponent<InteractIcons>().enabled = true;

    }
```

I tried assigning the button in the inspector to a variable and then added this variable like so `resumeBtn.Select();` in Pause() but it changed nothing.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Note that when the buttons are not highlighted, they get highlighted only after I press the arrows up or down or move the gamepad's analogue stick up or down. but at first, they are not highlighted.  How can I fix this?

Comment: If something works only once, it is usually an indication that you aren't resetting some flag. I cant see anything wrong with the code you provided, unless pauseMenuUI is something else than game object and its set active method does something else. Can you show your highlighting code?

Comment: I added all the related screenshots from the inspector. I don't get what you mean by highlighting code?

Comment: I thought you manage highlighting by yourself, but you are simply using button's built-in highlight, my bad

Answer (score 0):

In your event system you specified first selected to you resume button, however that seems to be not enough.

I'm not really sure how it works (this paragraph may be absolute bs), but after empirical research I think that event system sets its current selected item to the  first selected reference during its awake or start. On disable, it seems to clear its current selected, but doesn't set it again on its enable.

One way to tackle this problem is to manually set current selected item when bringing up pause menu: `eventSystem.SetSelectedGameObject(resumeButtonGameObject);` where eventSystem is obviousely of `EventSystem` type.

Comment: so the type of resumeButtonGameObject is GameObject, right? for some reason it is giving me this error: NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. even tho I assigned the button to the variable.

Comment: Yes, GameObject. Have you initialized your event system variable?

Comment: yea I just figured out it was the reason. So after testing now it never gets highlighted even if it is the first time pausing.

Comment: I placed it after pauseMenuUI.SetActive(true); now it didn't make any difference still after repausing the button gets unhighlighted.

Comment: Hmmm, it works on my end :P I assigned EventSystem from the scene to my eventSystem variable, then called this method inside the Pause() and it worked like a charm. Try to use debugger, and check if you got correct event system assigned and correct button, don't have more ideas.

Comment: but were you even having the same issue I'm facing here?

Comment: No, whenever I bring up pause menu I always have the resume button selected, now matter which was selected when I close the menu

Comment: So it is different for me. I don't know why it is not working it is driving me crazy T T.

Comment: On your menu you could simply do `private void OnEnable(){ EventSystem.current.SetSelectedGameObject(resumeButtonGameObject); }` Your issue is you have set the `First Selected` on the event system ... which indeed only means the very first time this scene is loaded